# why do properties not take on a new value from class method?

Tags: class, matlab, properties

I am trying to understand a little bit more about Matlab classes and their properties.  Here is a test class I have created:

```
classdef Test    
    properties
         % Properties of the network type
        some_var
    end

    methods
         function N = Test()
         end

        function change_var( N, val )
             N.some_var=val;
        end
    end
end
```

Now, I create an instance of this class, and call "change_var()"...

```
>> a=Test;
>> a.change_var(2);
>> a.some_var

ans =

     []
```

Why has the property "some_var" not taken on the value "val" in the assignment?

Comment: See [matlab classes: handle or value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436539/matlab-classes-handle-or-value) for a discussion of handle vs. value classes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Test` class has been defined as a [value-class as opposed to a handle class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html). Effectively, when you call `a.change_var`, `a` is passed in by-value. To store the change to the `some_var` property do this:

```
>> a = Test;
>> a = a.change_var(2);
```

The alternative is to make `Test` a handle class in which case the example in your question would work as you expected. To do this, inherit from the `handle` class by changing the first line of your class definition to this:

```
classdef Test < handle
```

Comment: bingo! that worked perfectly, thanks so much :)  I have to wait 4 minutes to select this as the answer, but will do

Comment: It's important to mention that once the class becomes **handle**, variables to which this class was assign to become reference to the same object in memory. Changing a property in one of those variables will change property value in the others similarly to object reference in c# for instance.

Answer (score 3):

The method provides for a way to change the property, but you should also return the object. You'll need to modify your method as:

```
function N = change_var( N, val )
     N.some_var=val;
end
```

Note that the function returns the modified object. Next, you'll need to update `a` with the change as:

```
a = a.change_var(2);
```

Comment: To be clear: the example shown here is for a value object class (ie: not a handle object), and it does not change the property of the original object per se. The function receives a _copy_ of the original object in the N argument, modifies that object's some_var property, and returns the modified copy of the object.