# Method does not update the current object MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a code using Matlab OO programming. I came across a problem trying to write a method that changes the value of a matrix inside the same object.
I've tested my method and it does exactly what I want it to do but it does not save back the results.

Here is my code:
Take a look on : function obj = initCC(obj)

%% searchDat picks values for the object properties in a fite
%% Importa a função searchDat()
%%

```
classdef methExpl
    %Classe de Metodos Explicitos
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    properties
        %Declara Altura da Placa, Largura, Nós em X, Nós em Y, K, Matriz
        %com a solução do passo atual, matriz com a solução do passo

        %Variáveis Geométricas
        %Altura e Largura
        Height
        Length
        %Variáveis da Malha
        %Número de nós em X e Número de nós em Y
        %Passo de tempo
        NodeX
        NodeY
        timeStep
        %Propriedades Físicas
        %Condutividade Térmica, Temperatura no Contorno
        %Temperatura Inicial uniforme na chapa

        kTerm
        boundaryTemp
        initTemp

        %Soluções parciais
        %Matriz com a solução da iteração atual
        %Matriz com a solução da iteração passada
        curMat
        lastMat

    end

    properties (SetAccess = private)
        %Arma
        funTermMAT
        erro = {}
    end

    methods
        function obj = methExpl()
            %Construtor da Classe
            %Inicializa as variaveis com os valores no arquivo input.dat
            %Inicializa a matriz 
            obj.Height = searchDat('[Height]','input.dat');
            obj.Length = searchDat('[Length]','input.dat');
            obj.NodeX = searchDat('[NodesX]','input.dat');
            obj.NodeY = searchDat('[NodesY]','input.dat');
            obj.kTerm = searchDat('[ThermalConductivity]','input.dat');
            obj.boundaryTemp = searchDat('[BoundaryTemperature]','input.dat');
            obj.initTemp = searchDat('[InitalTemperature]','input.dat');
            obj.curMat = zeros(obj.NodeX,obj.NodeY);
            %inicializa a matriz com a temperatura do contorno:
            obj.initCC();
            obj.lastMat = zeros(obj.NodeX,obj.NodeY);
        end



        function obj = initCC(obj)
        %initCC Inicializa a matriz com a condição de contorno de
        %temperatura
            lim = size(obj.curMat);
            for (i =1 : lim(1))
                for (j = 1 : lim(2))
                    if (i==1) || (i == lim(1))
                        obj.curMat(i,j) = obj.boundaryTemp;   
                    elseif (j==1) || (j ==lim(2))
                        obj.curMat(i,j) = obj.boundaryTemp
                    end

                end
            end
            obj.curMat
        end



    end

end
```

Before quitting the initCC and get:

```
ans =

     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

Which is exactly what I want.
If I call it from the outside after initializing it I get:

```
ans =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

As if the result of the method I have created has been destroyed.

Comment: When you call a method on a value class you need to store its output on the obj instance. Instead of obj.initCC() you need to use obj = obj.initCC(); See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086765/why-do-properties-not-take-on-a-new-value-from-class-method

Comment: Your class is a value class. For value classes, their methods copies `self` to a new object, modifies the new object, and return the new object. You need `new=0ld.initCC()` to get the result of the method.

Comment: However you can also change value class to handle class. For handle classes, methods modifies the `self` object directly and save the result back it `self`.

Comment: Is there any way my function can change the values within the object without having to take copying it back ? My object is going to be huge and a coppying operation is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put expand on the suggestions in the comments, you basically have two options. Firstly, you could simply capture the return of your `initCC` method which does correctly return the modified object, like so:

```
myObj = initCC(myObj);
```

Note that because of MATLAB's "copy on write" behaviour, this does not in fact incur any expensive copies of data.

The other option is to declare your class to be a `handle`, like so:

```
classdef methExpl < handle
...
end
```

then you don't need the return from `initCC`.