# Matlab - handle class

Tags: oop, class, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [matlab classes: handle or value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436539/matlab-classes-handle-or-value)

Regarding the `handle` class, you can see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) that it mentions the following about this class: `Objects that share references with other objects`.

What does this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It means handle objects are passed by reference, as explained [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html). Instead of copying the object when passing it as a function argument, which is the default behaviour in Matlab, a reference to it is passed.